# Need a recommendation for a router - available in europe

Tags: networking, router, ethernet

## Need recommendations valid for Europe, 2023

Please help me find a router available in 2023 in the European market.

### Summary

I am building my home infrastructure with Cat6A and switches. My use case requires implementation of multiple vlan networks, to support several users and shared resources. My search for a router which can support inter-vlan networking has be frustrating; vendors of routers do not explicitly stated how many vlan tags are supported, or how many active vlans are supported in their routers' datasheets. The router which I found, the Ubiquiti EdgeRouter X, might not be supported in the near future, and availability in Europe may be in question. Alternatives that do explicitly state their inter-vlan networking support beyond my budget.

### Research

Looking through the product catalog of vendors and manufacturers has been frustrating, because while they do state which standards they support, they do not explicitly state how many vlan networks the router supports; it may be as few as two networks, which is not acceptable.

The few which do explicitly state how many vlans are supported cost as much as a new computer, are meant for ISPs and not home use, and often have an impractical for me form factor. They often cost 600 USD to 5000 USD.

I did find the ERX from Ubiquiti, which supports 256 active vlans, is a small form factor which I can mount in a stack, and costs as little as 60 USD on their US site.

Prior experience with a retail router which claimed inter-vlan networking support only supports two vlans, the second being a limited guest network. I am careful now regarding vlan support and claims of supported standards made by routers and switches.

#### From Reddit

I have also asked on Reddit, but the answers are often out of scope, or non-constructive. I am unsure about the experience and expertise of users who reply. More often, my questions are not responded to in communities dedicated to home networking or brands.

#### From Quora

I have asked on Quora how to determine how many vlan networks a router supports. I asked what to look for in data sheets, and explained I am differentiating support of a standard from the number of vlans supported. The answers fell short, and were more like general advice, or criticisms and interrogations of why I would need or want an Ethernet network, vlans or a wired router over wifi.

#### From StackExchange

Recommendations are dated and not specific to the European market. A recommendation from 2011 is not relevant in 2023, because the recommended hardware may have been discontinued, become obsolete, or no longer the recommended solution in today's market. A recommendation not specific to the European market may be applicable for the US market, but not to the European market. This may be due to availability, taxes and duties, or not the recommended solution when a better option is available.

#### From Search Engines

I am flooded with *Top Ten Routers for 2023* lists written by marketers, influencers and compensated creators. Vendors and manufacturers do not appear in search results for *Routers without wifi*, *Wired routers* or *Routers supporting Vlans*, or when they do, it is for routers with WiFi and form factors I cannot mount or hide away.

### Requirements

1. Be available for purchase in 2023.
2. Be available in the EU market.
3. Support Dot1q.
4. Support Private vlan networks.
5. Support inter-vlan networking/routing.
6. Function with layer 2 switches that support port isolation.
7. Have a box shape.
8. Can be mounted without obstructing ports.
9. Cost less than 250 USD.
10. Has an OS with a GUI.
11. Doesn't require advanced knowledge of network engineering to implement vlans.
12. Does not have WiFi.

Comment: Would installing your own OS on 'existing' hardware be an option? If something like opensense supports your needs, you can throw it on a suitable x86 box and bob's your uncle

Comment: Also, what 'speeds' do you need your ethernet ports to be, how many, and are you looking for a rackmount?

Comment: Gigabit minimum. I don't need more than that to be honest.
But in the future, I may have use of multi gigabit ethernet for cluster computing.